# What is the correct way of having an image background that works on all devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I'm designing a website that has an image in the background (that *should* stretch and cover the whole page).

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height:100%;
}

body {
  background:url('../img/wide.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

However, this causes screen sizes that are less wide than my image have white bars on the top and bottom of the screens.

What is the accepted best way of doing this? Is it a CSS-only solution? Do I need to have a bunch of different images with different widths for every device? Is it a jQuery thing that requires reading the screen size and modifying the CSS (somehow - not sure what kind of CSS would fix this)?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: [`background-size: contain `](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), I'd imagine?

Comment: @DavidThomas, same issues if I switch it to contain

Comment: `background-size:100%` will only set the width to 100%, try `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: What's up with double values? `background-size: cover` should do exactly as you want, but you are overwriting that value with `background-size: 100%` which doesn't do what you want. You need `cover` for this. Remove the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parent div that will wrap the whole site like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="bodyWrap">
        ..YOUR SITE..
    </div>
</body>
```

And then add this to your css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
.bodyWrap    {
    background:url('../img/wide.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What's the downside of applying the background to the body instead?

Comment: The viewport is different from device to device so sometimes a 100% could expand the viewport of a small phone which leads to a space below the bg-img. How ever, if we keep a child div, it expands according to it's parent div (here, the body) so it doesn't matter if the viewport extends the 100% specified too

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only thing I changed was adding `min-height: 100%` to the wrapper so that pages that aren't "full" still have a complete background. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help Max :)

Comment: @maxmackie Please consider my comment and answer. Everything should work, you only wrote one rule extra. You don't need additional HTML markup to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What's up with double values? background-size: cover should do exactly as you want, but you are overwriting that value with background-size: 100% which doesn't do what you want. You need cover for this. Remove the last line.

```
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%; /* this rule will overwrite cover */
}
```

See the difference.

[background-size: 100%;](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/eeuta9L0/1/)

[background-size: cover;](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/eeuta9L0/)

So you should end up with:

```
body {
    background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Bananas.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

(**Note**: browser support is [good enough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) that you don't need prefixes, in my opinion.)

Comment: I tried this method before accepting the other answer and was still getting the same issues. I don't know why - because it works in JSFiddle.

Comment: @maxmackie In such cases you should find the issue in your own code otherwise you'll run into all sorts of other problems.